# Could not open "" Archive type not supported

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install Team-Speak 3 on Ubuntu 12.04, i've done all instructions that I should of, but when I run "ts3client_runscript.sh" it says "Could not open "ts3client_runscript.sh" archive type not supported"

How do i fix this

Answer (score 1):

It has to be executed. Right click on the file, select "Properties". Switch to the "Permissions" tab and check, at the bottom of the window, the option "Allow executing file as program".

It would also work great from the Terminal.

1) Open Terminal

2) `cd <directory where the file is>`

3) `chmod +x ts3client_runscript.sh`

4) `./ts3client_runscript.sh`

Comment: permission solved my issue